# Is it good for performance if multiple full text indexes of SQL Server are connected to one full text catalog?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Now my situation is as follows.

A table called `APPR_DOC_MASTER` was created to service multiple customers, and this table was created as a separate table by dividing it into schemas for each customer.

It is a situation where you need to create a full text index on this table, and it should be applied to all customer companies. Therefore, a full text index must be created for each `APPR_DOC_MASTER` table created for each customer.

In this case, can I create only one full text catalog created in the storage? Or should I create a separate full text catalog for each full text index and connect them?

I'd like to know which one is better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to have a table with a full-text index and catalog for all customers, that approach is for sure the easiest to manage, but it probably will be the less scalable approach and the approach that may have the lowest performance, and will not give to space for customizations.

If you can group customers by region or some other criteria, and have a table and catalog(s) by that criteria, this may reduce the number of catalogs to manage, it will have better performance and scalability than the first approach (explained on previous paragraph), and give you some space for some customizations by group of customers.

Having a separate table each table with its own catalo(g) will increase the cost and complexity of management and maintenance, but it will allow you space for customizations, and for sure the better performance.

Now it is time for you to decide what is most important for your organization in that scenario: performance, manageability, customization and/or customer isolation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll accept your opinion.

Comment: You are welcome! What is the best fit in your scenario?

Comment: I think it would be better to create a catalog for each client company.